# .FindNext doesn't search for the same criteria in .Find (Overwriting/Overriding)

Tags: excel, vba

Ive tried searching through multiple sites for resolution but couldn't find.

I have multiple tables in a single sheet and using a findnext loop to search for "Ven1"  address in each of the table.
But at the same time want to rearrange rows and columns in that particular table hence using .find function.

Now at the end of operation in 1 table, the .findnext doesnt find address of "Ven1" in another table but considers the last result of .find (used for rearrangement)

I am thinking that .find used for operation is overwriting/overriding .find to search "Ven1" position.

Please let me know if there is a way out to use both in one sub, or creating function would help

Below is the code

```
WS.Select

    With Worksheets(WS.Name)
    xyz = "Ven1"
        '(Not helping) - Set dr = Cells.Find(What:=xyz, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchformat:=False)

        Set dr = Cells.Find(What:=xyz, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not dr Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = dr.Address

            Do
                r = dr.Row
                c = dr.Column

                checkrow = InStr(1, Cells(r + 1, c).Value, "Ven")
                checkcol = InStr(1, Cells(r, c + 1).Value, "Ven") Or Cells(r, c + 1).Value = ""
                If checkrow = 1 Then
                counter = r
                End If

                If checkcol = 1 Then
                counter = c
                End If

                For new_index = LBound(new_row_order) To UBound(new_row_order)

                    If checkrow = 1 Then

                        Set found = Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(lrow1 + r - 1, c)).Find(new_row_order(new_index), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

                        If Not found Is Nothing Then

                            If found.Row <> counter Then
                                x = found.Row
                                y = found.Column
                                CN = Cells(x, y).End(xlToRight).Column
                                Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, CN)).Cut
                                Cells(counter, y).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            End If
                            counter = counter + 1
                        End If

                    Else
                        If checkcol = 1 Then

                            Set found = Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, lrow1 + c - 1)).Find(new_row_order(new_index), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                            If Not found Is Nothing Then

                                If found.Column <> counter Then
                                    x = found.Row
                                    y = found.Column
                                    RN = Cells(x, y).End(xlDown).Row
                                    Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(RN, y)).Cut
                                    Cells(x, counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                                End If
                                counter = counter + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

                Next new_index

            Set dr = Cells.FindNext(dr)

   'The above Set dr = cells.findnext(dr) is not setting "Ven1" rather its setting the dr as last value in the list of rearrangement operation

            Loop While Not dr Is Nothing And dr.Address <> FirstAddress

        End If
    End With
End If
Next WS
```

Comment: That is how `.Find` and `.FindNext` works.  The last used settings are retained.  How to work around it depends on factors not shown.  But clearly, you should not be using `.FindNext` if there is another `.Find` statement executed after the one whose settings you want to retain.  Just use `.Find` and set the parameters.

Comment: Hey, thanks Ron!
Have removed the .find function loop and now using just findnext loop.
It correctly sets the next address of same criteria.
Finally managed to make it work though. :)